# Flask MQTT on_connect is never called when used with SocketIO

Tags: flask, socket.io, mqtt

I am trying to implement an MQTT to Web Socket bridge on the lines of
https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#interact-with-socketio

In the above example, subscribing to the MQTT topic is triggered by the socket client. But I want my MQTT channel to keep communicating even if there is no socket client.

So I tried to subscribe in the @mqtt.on_connect() event. But that callback is never invoked.
But once subscription is initiated using a socket, MQTT messages start flowing in all right.

I have implemented Flask MQTT apps without involving web sockets, and they work fine. Does SocketIO in some way interfere with MQTT life cycle events ?

Here is the minimal code:

```
# Flask MQTT Web socket bridge
 
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from flask import Flask, render_template 
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET'] = 'my-secret'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'localhost'      
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False  
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

mqtt = Mqtt(app)
socketio = SocketIO (app, async_mode='gevent', cors_allowed_origins="*")  

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
@socketio.on('connect')
def on_socket_connect ():
    print ('Connected to socket client.')
    mqtt.subscribe('mytopic')  
    
# This is never called:
@mqtt.on_connect()  
def on_mqtt_connect (client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print ('Connected to MQTT broker.')
    #mqtt.subscribe ('mytopic')   # this would be ideal
    
@mqtt.on_message()
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    socketio.send (message.payload.decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you just using the built-in webserver for the Flask/HTTP portion?  If you're using uwsgi I wonder if it's something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553334/mqtt-messages-not-received-when-flask-client-is-run-behind-uwsgi

Comment: @Dan, I am using gevent server. The plain Flask app.run() is not an option for me, as I the main loop has to be under the control of SocketIO. Btw, I found a workaround for the problem following the link you have shared. I eliminated Flask-MQTT and now I directly use paho MQTT library. I start my own MQTT loop before running the app loop. This works fine, that is, I am getting the on_connect() callback now.

Comment: @Raja can i have the source code.. i also tried this solution. mqtt connects but the on_connect function indefinitely being called when i try to connect with my local mosquitto server.

Answer (score 0):

@NagaRajS, I came to the conclusion that it is not currently possible to get the MQTT onConnect callback work within Flask. This is the outline of my solution that does not use Flask MQTT:

```
# Flask socketIO server with classical Paho MQTT  
# Unlike the Flask-MQTT version, this correctly calls MQTT on_connect()

from flask import Flask, render_template
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

sub_topic = 'my/sub/topic'
pub_topic = 'my/pub/topic'
server = 'localhost'
MQTTport = 1883
client = None

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO (app, async_mode='gevent', cors_allowed_origins="*") 

# SocketIO

@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect ():
    print ('Socket client connected.')
    socketio.send ('Socket server ready.')

@socketio.on ('message')    
def on_publish (payload):
    client.publish (pub_topic, payload)
    
# MQTT
   
def on_connect (client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('* Connected to MQTT broker *')
    client.subscribe (sub_topic, qos=0)  
    client.publish (pub_topic, 'MQTT server ready.')

def on_message (client, userdata, msg):
    socketio.send (msg.payload.decode())

# HTTP

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('bridge.html')
    
# Main  
  
client = mqtt.Client("Mqtt-socket-bridge-2021", clean_session=True)   
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(server, MQTTport, keepalive=60)

print ('Starting the MQ loop..')
client.loop_start()   

print ('Starting the socket server on port 5000...')    
socketio.run (app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

bridge.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MQTT WebSock bridge</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

     socket.on('connect', function()
     {
        console.log ("Connected to socket server.");
     });

     socket.on('message', function(msg)
     {  
        console.log (msg);
        socket.send ('Received: '+msg)
     });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am also having this issue, and also had use_reloader=True which causes reconnections on the broker.

Thank you for this. Because of this I am going to take a different path and have the mqtt client as a separate thread and use socketio to push to the flask thread as my issue I saw is that there were multiple subscriptions to the topic in flask which means since I have code that sends messages back on different topics I was getting duplicate messages.

Appreciate this thread.