# Python flask mqtt socketio and subscribing on startup

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

When starting a flask, mqtt and socketio app how exactly can I subscribe to topics when the app starts but before the browser connects for the first time?

I had assumed I could use `before_first_request` but that only gets called on first request, also assume I could use `mqtt.on_connect` but that is never called when using socket io and if I subscribe before starting the app in `__main__` then I get two threads subscribed rather than one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

# Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = '192.168.109.135'
print('Configured MQTT IP Address: ' + app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'])

mqtt = Mqtt(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def roots():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/mqtt')
def mqtt_index():
    return render_template('mqtt.html')

@socketio.on('subscribe')
def handle_subscribe(json_str):
    print('Subscribe ' + json_str)

@socketio.on('unsubscribe_all')
def handle_unsubscribe_all():
    print('Socket IO unsubscribe all')
    mqtt.unsubscribe_all()

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Socket IO Connected')

@socketio.on('discconnect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Socket IO Discconnect')

@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_mqtt_connect():
    print('MQTT Connected')

@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    print('MQTT Message')
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode(),
        qos=message.qos,
    )
    print(mqttresponse)
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)

@mqtt.on_log()
def handle_logging(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print('MQTT log', level, buf)
    pass

@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    print("before_first_request")
    mqtt.subscribe('homeassistant/+/+/set', 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main http web server for firmware downloading and the main frontend.
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='6080', use_reloader=True)
```

Any ideas where the `mqtt.subscribe` should go so it subscribes to the topics I want before the first connect to the webserver?

Comment: Have you tried doing it right above the `socketio.run()` call? That's the earliest place, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I found there is already a related issue which is the on_connect callback doesn't get called, and a question on here too. So this is a duplicate.

[Flask MQTT on_connect is never called when used with SocketIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592277/flask-mqtt-on-connect-is-never-called-when-used-with-socketio)

https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT/issues/82